# Asp.Net MVC how to store global information that can handle multiple requests (threads)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, global-variables

I apologize if my question is not descriptive enough. I have an MVC application that has multiple company accounts. So I have company users and I have customer users. Customer users decide which company they want to do business with and log in. They can obviously do business with company1 first, then log out and log in to do business with company2.

I have the _Layout.cshtml page and in it, I want to be able to customize the page according to the company that the customer user logged in to. At first, I created global static variables but that doesn't work because after user1 logs into company1, when user2 logs into company2 it changes the information displayed to user1 so suddenly he's looking at company2.

In my layout page, I want to display for example the company name and more like that. To show what I did first I created this class:

```
namespace Hylton
{
    public class G
    {
        public static string OrgName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static int OrgId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static string OrgEmail
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml I had something like this:

```
<li class="hi-logo">
    <a href="~/" class="m-l-10">
        @G.OrgName
    </a>
</li>
```

Is there a good way to do this without looking up in the database every time?

Comment: Why static? Why not normal properties?

Comment: Ok, what would be the best way for that? BaseViewModel that all view model use and populate it in base controller?

Comment: You can use BaseViewModel. Or you can pass company name in viewdata or viewbag.

Comment: Ok, but How can I prevent multiple database lookups because this information doesn't change?

Comment: Web applications are state less so you need to get fresh data during every request processing. You can either store that information in some cache to avoid database trips. If you are using model class then you can render the company name in the view with hidden control so when you post the form you get that back as part of your model property.

Comment: `Web applications are state less so you need to get fresh data during every request processing. ` this is just wrong :) Web apps are long-running processes that retain data in memory just like normal apps do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is have `SessionState` for a given user. Depending on your authentication mechanism, you may be able to store this in actual session in MVC e.g. after user logs in, in the controller do:

`this.Session["CompanyName"] = "Shoes";`

Then you can extract this in your view rendering:

```
public ViewResult Whatever()
{
  var g = new G{OrgName = this.Session["CompanyName"]};
  return this.View(g);
}
```

Another option would be to store this in the cookie or authentication token.

The idea is the same, however - the user logs in, and their browser (and sometimes your server) persists certain information about this company they are working with.